# Joining two Array[Byte] in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

Pretty straightforward problem that I can't find a good solution for:

```
val a1 = Array[Byte](1, 2, 3)
val a2 = Array[Byte](4, 5, 6)
```

How can I join these two arrays together? I don't mind if the first array is extended by the second.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, suddenly it was very easy to find after I asked!

```
val joinArray = a1 ++ a2
```